# show directly from the definition is Cauchy sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I can't show directly from the definition that the following is Cauchy sequence, please help me : ( only directly from definition)

$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{1!}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n!}\right)$

Comment: Questions posted here should not be phrased in a way suitable for assigning homework.  If you have actual questions about how to show these are Cauchy sequences, then post your questions.

Comment: Hint: what is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}$?

Comment: Mrc but This is not directly from definition

Answer (score -1):

**Note (updated due to question change):** The OP initially considered the sequence $(1, 1/2, 1/3, ..., 1/n)$ and asked if it was Cauchy. This part has been recently deleted from the post.

First we define a Cauchy sequence:

\begin{align}
\forall\; \varepsilon >0, \exists N\; \text{such that}\; \forall\; m, n \geq N, d(a_{m}, a_{n}) < \varepsilon
\end{align}
and recall Lagrange's remainder theorem for $e^{x}$ for $x_{0}=0$, $x=1$ and some $x_{*} \in (0,1)$:

\begin{align}
\left |e^{x} - \sum_{j=0}^{n} \frac{x^{j}}{j!} \right | &\leq R_{n+1}(x) = \frac{(e^{x})^{(n+1)}(x_{*})}{(n+1)!}(x-x_{0})^{n+1} = \frac{e^{x_{*}}}{(n+1)!} \leq \frac{e}{(n+1)!}.
\end{align}

One can now prove the statement directly.

**Proof:** First define $a_{n} = \sum_{j=0}^{n} \frac{1}{j!}, \, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Next fix $\varepsilon>0$. Then, by Lagrange's remainder theorem, one can choose $N > \frac{e}{\varepsilon}$ such that $d(a_{m}, a_{n}) = \sum\limits_{j=m+1}^{n} \frac{1}{j!}\leq \frac{e}{(m+1)!} \leq \frac{e}{N} < \varepsilon$, where $n \geq m \geq N$ and so the sequence is Cauchy. The sequence also converges, but that is a different question.